# How to normalize data series to start value = 0?

Tags: r, ggplot2, normalization, series

I have a dataset similar to this:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(economics_long)
economics_long$date2 <- as.numeric(economics_long$date) + 915
ggplot(economics_long, aes(date2, value01, colour = variable)) +
       geom_line()
```

Which gives the following plot:

[image]

Now I  would like to normalize it to the start value of the green line (or the mean), so all variables start at the same point of the Y axes. Similar to this:

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe add a value `0` at the start of each time series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subtract the starting value of each vector depending on `variable`-value using `by()`.

```
library(ggplot2)
l <- by(economics_long, economics_long$variable, function(x) 
  within(x, varnorm <- value01 - value01[1]))
dat <- do.call(rbind, l)

ggplot(dat, aes(date2, value01.n, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Great, to use by() and split() to generate lists was new to me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### use `group_by()` and `mutate()` to shift each variable by its initial y-value.

```
library(tidyverse)
data(economics_long)

economics_long %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  mutate(value_shifted = value01 - value01[1]) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date2, value_shifted, colour = variable)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]